# Replace null values in cell

Tags: openrefine

I am unable to replace null values in cells. I have created a facet to only display cells that have null values. I then went to edit cells > Transform function and tried to use the [replace function](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#replacestring-s-string-f-string-r) but it does not seem to be working.

Different things I have tried:

```
replace(value, null, 'other_text')
replace(value, 'null', 'other_text')
```

I expected the null values to be replaced with 'other text'

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You are not replacing the value `null`, but the string `'null'`. The correct syntax for replacing is `value.replace('old','new')` or `replace(value,'old','new')`. But replacing doesn't work on `null`. You should either create a facet for null-values (your current screenshot shows some non-null-values) and fill the expression field with `'new'` or you could do something like `if(value==null,'new',value)`.

Comment: That seemed to work. I was not aware that replacing does not work on null. It is not documented anywhere. Side note, I had tried the value null. I only tried 'null' when the value null did not work. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisSmith Let's say it's implicitly indicated. the `replace()` function/method [requires 3 strings](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#replacestring-s-string-f-string-r) or 1 regex and 2 strings. But `null` is not a string. `null` is emptiness, the absence of value. That's why Open Refine has one facet for `null` and another for the empty string "", which looks like null, but which is a real string despite the fact that it contains nothing.

Comment: @EttoreRizza That makes sense. However, that is not documented anywhere. At the very least it should be mentioned in the function/method link you posted.

Comment: Please do edit the wiki if you want to add more precisions about this. You can do it!

Comment: I updated the wiki just now to explain further:   https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#replacestring-s-string-f-string-r